# Are `h` and `createVNode` the same?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, virtual-dom, vue-render-function

Both `h` and `createVNode` are exposed from `vue`.

The [doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#h-arguments) seems to suggest they are the same:

> The h() function is a utility to create VNodes. It could perhaps more accurately be named **createVNode()**.

But switch `h` to `createVNode` will throw:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { createVNode, defineComponent, h } from 'vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      // works
      return () => h('strong', 'Foo')

      // throws
      return () => createVNode('strong', 'Foo')
    },
  })
</script>
```

Comment: As the docs mention, they are not the same. `createVNode` would be a better name.. but it's still called `h`.

Comment: `createVNode` is exposed from `vue` tho, so they are supposed to act the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `h`:

> [props can be omitted when there are no props](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#creating-vnodes)

You can just do:

```js
h('strong', 'Foo')
```

For `createVNode`, you have to do:

```js
createVNode('strong', null, 'Foo')
```

Answer (score 6):

`createVNode` is exposed but `h` is the user friendly variant of it. If you want to call `createVNode` directly you should add different type of arguments, see:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/060c5f1d0ae999cd8c8fb965e8526ffab17ac2d1/packages/runtime-core/src/vnode.ts#L326

```
    export const createVNode = (__DEV__
      ? createVNodeWithArgsTransform
      : _createVNode) as typeof _createVNode

    function _createVNode(
      type: VNodeTypes | ClassComponent | typeof NULL_DYNAMIC_COMPONENT,
      props: (Data & VNodeProps) | null = null,
      children: unknown = null,
      patchFlag: number = 0,
      dynamicProps: string[] | null = null,
      isBlockNode = false
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//h method Actual implementation
function h(type, propsOrChildren, children) {
    const l = arguments.length;
    if (l === 2) {
        if (isObject(propsOrChildren) && !isArray(propsOrChildren)) {
            // single vnode without props
            if (isVNode(propsOrChildren)) {
                return createVNode(type, null, [propsOrChildren]);
            }
            // props without children
            return createVNode(type, propsOrChildren);
        }
        else {
            // omit props
            return createVNode(type, null, propsOrChildren);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (l > 3) {
            children = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        }
        else if (l === 3 && isVNode(children)) {
            children = [children];
        }
        return createVNode(type, propsOrChildren, children);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).